# Debouncing in react with multiple factors

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

I have a bunch of images with each image having the following data,

```
{
id: '',
src: '',
count: ''
}
```

Now I need to update the count on the DB upon clicking the image.
Now to reduce the API calls, I used debounce over here, but as you can see there are 2 dependencies.

```
id as well as count.
```

How do I go about implementing a debounce on these 2 variables?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a queue of the click events.

```
ClicksQueue -> [ {id: 123}, {id: 124}, {id: 125}, {id: 123} ]
```

Every time a click happens, you push an event to the queue and also trigger a debounced API request.

Whenever the API request gets invoked, you can just consume all the messages from the queue, combine the messages with same id into one, and then send the request.

For example, in the above queue, image with id as `123` was clicked twice and all others were just clicked once. So, send that data to the server.

One recommendation, instead of sending the count from the UI, send the increment and decrement values instead which would be safe if you have multiple people clicking on the images.

Comment: Great answer, but I didn't get your last recommendation though

Comment: So, currently, I think you are sending the total clicks on the image to the server. If the image was initially clicked 5 times and then you click twice, then you send `7` to the server. Instead of this, you can send increment as `+2` and then let the server handle the increment for you as it would be transaction-safe.

Comment: Got it, missed that. What about if I didn't sent the no. of clicks? can i still catch it on the backend and with minimum api calls? No right? Like i should call the api each and every time i click isn't it?

Comment: If you don't combine the events, then you will have to make different API call for each click.

Comment: which breaks the debounce use case right?

Comment: That is correct.